# How to pass kwargs further?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wms, keyword-argument

I have an outer function `wms130.getfeatureinfo` in [`OWSLib`](https://geopython.github.io/OWSLib/), which uses kwargs:

```
def getfeatureinfo(self, layers=None,
...
                       method='Get',
                       timeout=None,
                       **kwargs
                       ):
```

and I have usage of kwargs in inner function `wms130.__build_getmap_request`:

```
    ...
    request['transparent'] = str(transparent).upper()
    request['bgcolor'] = '0x' + bgcolor[1:7]
    request['exceptions'] = str(exceptions)

    if time is not None:
        request['time'] = str(time)

    if elevation is not None:
        request['elevation'] = str(elevation)

    # any other specified dimension, prefixed with "dim_"
    for k, v in six.iteritems(dimensions):
        request['dim_' + k] = str(v)

    if kwargs:
        for kw in kwargs:
            request[kw]=kwargs[kw]
    return request
```

Apparently, the intention of the author was to put all keyworded arguments into parameters of HTTP query as is.

Unfortunately, when I pass my kwarg to outer function it has a value

```
{'MAXCC': '100'}
```

but when reaching this inner code it has a value

```
{'kwargs': {'MAXCC': '100'}}
```

i.e. extra level added. This is because the inner function is called with

```
# GetMap-Request
        request = self.__build_getmap_request(
            layers=layers,
            styles=styles,
            srs=srs,
            bbox=bbox,
            dimensions=dimensions,
            elevation=elevation,
            format=format,
            size=size,
            time=time,
            transparent=transparent,
            bgcolor=bgcolor,
            exceptions=exceptions,
            kwargs=kwargs)
```

i.e. outer kwargs is wrapped into single keyworded argument with name `kwargs`.

The question is dual:

1) How probable it is a bug in OWSLib and the intention was to put kwargs expanded? (I would say it is 99%, because there is no need to add loop to iterate over dictionary with single known entry)

2) How to call inner function in Python to have kwargs passed as kwargs, not as single entry?

Comment: so this is not your code but the module OWSlib? I would say yes, this seems like an error on their part, but perhaps there is a reason for the behaviour.

Comment: Adding any extra argument causes sentinel hub web API to crash, because `kwargs` appears as explicit HTTP argument. So there is 1% they had a reason for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *unpacking* to pass the previous `kwargs` further down. Don't introduce a new keyword argument for it:

```
request = self.__build_getmap_request(
            ...
            exceptions=exceptions,
            **kwargs)
```

All of these keyword arguments and the unpacked `kwargs` will be captured in the next level `kwargs`.

More so, the request dict can be updated using a simple `dict.update` as opposed to looping:

```
request.update(kwargs)
```